# just inlcude inline-leave box and have a 'display:flow-root',Will the div form a BFC or IFC？

Tags: css

Will the div form a BFC (block formatting context) or IFC (inline formatting context)?

```html
<div style="display: flow-root;">
  <span>你好</span>
</div>
```

This div simultaneously satisfies：

1. An inline formatting context is established by a block container box that contains no block-level boxes.
2. display is flow-root

so，What exactly is it, and who can analyze the reasons?

Comment: @DarkBee block formatting context / inline formatting context.

Comment: Please explain what a BFC or IFC is? 
It's difficult to describe, but everyone, including myself, generally agrees that a "Formatting Context (FC) is an independent rendering area, adhering to certain layout rules." Specifically, concerning Block Formatting Context (BFC), it refers to conditions being triggered to form a BFC. Once a BFC is established, the elements inside the box will follow the layout rules of the BFC, such as vertical arrangement, margin collapsing, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` for a BFC because you have `display: flow-root`. We don't really care about its content type when we have a property that explicitly define a BFC.

Now that your element form a BFC it should contain only block level elements but you have an inline one. To overcome this, there is the concept of ["Anonymous block boxes"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)

In your case, the span element (an **inline** element) will get wrapped within an anonymous **block** box to make sure the BFC created by the div contain only block-level elements. Then the new anonymous box will be the IFC for your span element